# Calling read from inside shell script causes program to hang

Tags: bash, shell

Calling read from inside of a function in a bash shell script causes the script to hang.  Can somebody kindly explain why this happens, and how to call read without this happening?  Consider the MWE below.

```
#!/bin/bash

hangup () {
    read choice < /dev/tty
}

hangup
```

Thanks!

---

Edit:  the above of course totally works.  My problem was extracted from a larger program where I was setting a variable using a command substitution construct.  So for example,

```
myvar=$(hangup)
```

But there was a loop containing the read call inside the function and the text was getting redirected to the variable so it had the appearance of hanging up even though things were happening - I just couldn't tell because the output wasn't showing up in stdout (well of course not!).

Sorry about the foolish question.  If there is a way to close this question that would be great.

Comment: why are you using `< /dev/tty`? Just `read var` will wait for input and after the Enter key is pressed, the input is assigned to the `var`. But, I would expect what you have will work, as long as you hit the Enter key. Your example could benefit from sample input and expected action. Good luck!

Comment: You're right it does work, the MWE isn't capturing the problem that I'm trying to extract from a larger program.  I'll try to reformulate the example - thanks for your comment and the gracious answer.

Comment: If you have a program like `strace` available it can be very useful when a program appears to "hang".  `strace -p` *pid* is useful here, if you run it on your example it will tell you it is trying to read from file descriptor 0 (stdin).

Comment: Your example works for me as expected, even the `myvar=$(hangup)` part. The program hangs until I hit ENTER. Could you please clarify what does not work as expected?

Comment: @sapanoia Yes indeed you are correct that the example works as expected, even the `myvar=$(hangup)` part.  I mistakenly thought that it was hanging up because it was part of a loop where the user was prompted for input and then if the input wasn't valid the program would loop around again until valid input was provided.  Since due to the command substitution construct I wasn't able to see what the prompt was, I was hitting enter many times with seemingly no response, which was what caused me to mistakenly think the program had hung up.  Thanks for for the question and sorry about the mistake.